# PHP CLI - which command should I use?

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I have one server (test) which has "php" command that I can run CLI with. The other server (hosting) runs only with "php5-cli" command.

Example:

```
exec("php file.php"); // Works on test server
exec("php5-cli file.php"); // Works on hosting server
```

How can my script detect which one to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a config value specific to each server. On some servers you will encounter `php5` as a cli command, instead of php:) And the system administrator may easily rename or symlink the executable to any name he likes.

---

edit:
try something along the lines of :

```
$output = Array();
$result = -1;
exec("php -f myScript.php", $output, $result);
if($result==-1){
    // you should try to exec use the other method here
    echo "app 'php' not found";
}else{
    // the exec was a success
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you symlink `php-cli` as `php` or vise versa?

That way either would work.

Comment: He explicitly states that `php` doesn't work on his host server, hence his question.

Answer (score 1):

```
php-config --php-binary
php-config5 --php-binary
```

But you probably run into similar problems of no guarantee what that command is called (or that it exists). Not sure how many hosting companies use it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure which php.ini is included when using each of them.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make a symlink to the executable on one of the servers `ln -s` so that one of them is available on both servers.

That should solve this problem.